# How to select some columns from a row with two conditions?

Tags: mysql

I trying to display a row from a table where the two conditions are:
1) The student with the highest gpa 
2) application date before YYYY-MM-DD.

The reason I didn't use * for Select is because there are some columns I don't want to be displayed.

```
SELECT firstName
    ,lastName
    ,applicationDate
    ,gpa
FROM Student
WHERE MAX(gpa) 
AND applicationDate < 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I am having issues with writing my conditions statement.

when I type the code like this:

```
SELECT firstName
    ,lastName
    ,applicationDate
    ,MAX(gpa)
FROM Student
WHERE applicationDate < 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

It will display data from different rows.

Comment: Order your table by gpa and limit to 1 result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `LIMIT` here:

```
SELECT
    firstName,
    lastName,
    applicationDate,
    gpa
FROM Student
WHERE applicationDate < 'YYYY-MM-DD'
ORDER BY
    gpa DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This doesn't handle the case where two or more students could be tied for the highest GPA.  In that case, we could either use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
WHERE gpa = (SELECT MAX(gpa) FROM Student WHERE applicationDate < 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Or we could use the `RANK` analytic function, if you are using MySQL 8+.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by and limit to get the desired result, like this:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, applicationDate, gps WHERE applicationDate < 'YYYY-MM-DD' ORDER BY gpa DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

select max(gpa) as GPA from Table where date < '2019-01-11'